# How to change anchor class from different page in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu, anchor

i have a menu in my application layout
say

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="dashboard.asp">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="/people">People</a></li>
 </ul>
```

now i would like to change the class of different anchor from different page... say for the home page it will be like ...

```
  <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="dashboard.asp">Dashboard</a></li>
     <li><a href="/people">People</a></li>
  </ul>
```

how to achieve this ? BTW i'm new to ror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

Write a helper method to do this (helper methods are for do some simple functions for presentation layout, this is an ideal case).

In Rails you can get the currently executing controller name as

```
params[:controller]
```

and executing action as

```
params[:action]
```

So in your application helper you can write something like

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def active_link (link)
    (link == params[:controller]) ? "active" : ""
  end
end
```

In above example, if the current controller matches current link, then it will return a string as "active" or else return a blank string

Finally in your view,

```
<ul>
     <li><a class="<%= active_link('home') %>" href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="<%= active_link('dashbord') %>">Dashboard</a></li>
     <li><a href="<%= active_link('people') %>">People</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Notes**

- This solution assumes that you have a controller with matching name
  for each link.
- I haven't tested this, but should be working, but this should be the
  concept

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to pass an instance variable from your controller. For example, if you're sent to the home page:

```
class Pages < ApplicationController
  def index
    @active = "index"
  end
end
```

Now, when you're in the navigation view, you'd do something like:

```
<li><a class="<%= "active" if @active == "index" %>" href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you could also override `link_to`:

```
def link_to(*args, &block)
  options_key, html_key = block_given? ? [0, 1] : [1, 2]

  args[html_key] ||= {}
  args[html_key][:class] = [args[html_key][:class], "active"].compact.join(' ') if current_page?(args[options_key])

  super(*args, &block)
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", "index.asp" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", "dashboard.asp" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "People", "/people" %></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`link_to_unless_current`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current) helper which does what you need, although not always as expected - it ignores the query params. But if all your links point to different actions/controllers, that should do.